# Como renderizar uma estrutura de partials de outro diretório no Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

**1) Estrutura de views**

Supondo que eu tenha dois conjuntos de views, o conjunto A e o conjunto B.
Ambos conjuntos são semelhantes possuindo a view `index.html.erb` e as *partials* `_index.html.erb`, `_new.html.erb`, `_edit.html.erb`, `_table.html.erb`, `_show.html.erb`, `_bean.html.erb`, `_form.html.erb` e `_field.html.erb`.

**2) Relação entre views**

Ambas também possui um formato semelhante onde a view `index.html.erb` renderiza a partial `_index.html.erb`;
A partial `_index.html.erb` renderiza as partials `_new.html.erb`, `_edit.html.erb`, `_table.html.erb`, `_show.html.erb`;
Tanto a partial `_edit.html.erb` quanto a `_new.html.erb` renderizam a partial `_form.html.erb`; 
A partial `_form.html.erb` redeniza a partial `_fiels.html.erb`;
E as partials `_show.html.erb` e `_table.html.erb` rederizam a partial `_bean.html.erb`.

**3) Relação entre os dois grupos de views**

Porém na minha lógica, o objeto A possui uma relação de um para muitos com o objeto B, e a view `a/index` também renderiza a partial `b/_index`.

**4)Problema**

Ao implementar o seguinte código `render partial: 'b/index'` em `a/index.html.erb` o conteudo do arquivo `b/_index.html.erb` é inserido corretamente, porém o mesmo renderiza as partials da pasta `a` e não mais as da `b`. Exemplo: é renderizado `a/_show.html.erb` ao invés de `b/_show.html.erb`.

**5) Dúvida**

Contudo tem como eu determinar a partial a ser renderizada, com base no diretório da partial que a referenciou no lugar do diretório da view corrente?

Comment: Tem como exibir a estrutura de diretórios para ficar mais claro?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode colocar o caminho inteiro do arquivo, no caso que exista uma partial inserida em app/views/users/_map.html.erb você pode fazer a chamada assim

```
<%= render 'users/map' %>
```

e no caso de precisar especificar uma variavel interna ao partial é só adicionar o parametro

```
<%= render 'users/map', lat: @lat, lng: @lng %>
```

users/_map.html.erb

```
<div>
  <p>lat:<%= lat %></p>
  <p>lng:<%= lng %></p>
</div>
```

e se precisar especificar uma colection pra um partial que tenha o nome do model ex: 'users/_user.html.erb'

```
<!--coloque o partial e especifique qual coleção de dados irá usar-->
<% render partial: 'users/user', collection: @guests %>
```